# How to apply sheet protection?

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation is a little unclear about the protection of a sheet in the Excel style. (Or, I may just not be reading it right).

I have protected a Spreadsheet by placing it in a directory with access control that defines editors and readers. I want to lock a sheet in this Spreadsheet so that no one can edit it, but anyone with edit permission on the rest of the document can remove the lock.

When I apply a protection, it seems that I cannot remove myself, so I can always edit the sheet. When I try the example via a script and remove the `me` bit, I can still edit the sheet. If I add this lock via a script running as a service account I can lock the sheet so nobody else can edit it, but, no one can remove the lock.

Here is my simple modified version of the third example on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) that seems to work.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Protect the active sheet, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Test Protection');

  // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
  // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  //protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

I could probably set up a menu item to run a trigger as the service account to unlock the tab, but that seems a bit of a chore, especially given the speed of triggers.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think editors are identified by email address. Add `getEmail()` to `me` and see if that helps.

Comment: I don't want any user to edit the contents until the lock is removed by anyone who can edit the file, then any editor can edit the contents as normal. Look at the way Excel does it. Anyone can lock the sheet and not edit the content, then, anyone can remove the lock and edit the contents. This is what I'm after.